# Restriction of a sheaf to an infinitely small neighbourhood of a closed submanifold: how to work with this ind-sheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory, ct.category-theory, reference-request

Let $X$ be a manifold, $i: Z\to X$ is a closed embedding.

For a sheaf $S$ (of abelian groups) on a manifold $X$ and each  $\varepsilon>0$ we  denote by $Z_\varepsilon$ the set of points of $X$ that lie at distance $<\varepsilon$ from $X$. Consider the sheaf $S_\varepsilon:U\mapsto S(U\cap Z_\varepsilon)$, and also the section-wise limit $S_Z=\injlim_{\varepsilon\to 0} S_\varepsilon$.

I would like to understand the functor $W: S\to S_Z$ (I do not want to describe it section-wisely). Unfortunately, $S_Z$ is only an in-sheaf; it does not have to be a sheaf (in the 'usual' sense; note that the topological space $X$ is not noetherian). In particular,  the stalk of $S_Z$ at any point $x\notin Z$ is easily seen to be $0$ (since $S_Z(U)=0$ for any $U$ such that its closure is disjoint from $Z$). On the other hand, the section $S_Z(X\setminus Z)$ does not seem to be $0$ (for example, if $S$ is constant); note that $X\setminus Z$ is not compact! See here the answer of algori to a previous version of this question (yesterday I believed that one can call $S_Z$ a sheaf).

Any hints (or references) for dealing with my $W$ would be very welcome! Note that $W$ is the limit of $i_{\varepsilon\ast}i_{\varepsilon}^\ast$. Unfortunately, the adjunctions that I wrote about previously probably do not hold (in any sense).

P.S. Some observations that do not seem to help me.

1. My definition of $S_Z$ extends (without any changes) to presheaves.
2. $W':P\mapsto P_Z$ sends ind-sheaves to ind-sheaves.
3. It seems that ind-sheaves are (exactly) sheaves for the Grothendieck topology that admits only 'finite' covers.

So, perhaps one should use (somehow) the interplay between sheaves, ind-sheaves, and presheaves (and the corresponding topologies).

Comment: Mikhail -- I'm not sure I understand your construction of $S_Z$. It looks to me that if $\epsilon_1<\epsilon 2$, then $S_{\epsilon_1}$ maps to $S_{\epsilon_2}$, not the other way around, so the limit should be projective, not injective. In general, I don't know if `$i_*i^{-1}$` has a left adjoint, but it has a right adjoint, `$i_!i^!$.

Comment: Well, $Z_{\epsilon_1}\subset Z_{\epsilon_2}$ in this case; hence we have a map $S_{\epsilon_2}\to S_{\epsilon_1}$. This is a sort of a stalk at $Z$. 

Comment: Mikhail -- the way I understand what you say, you restrict the sheaf to $Z_{\epsilon}$ and then extend by 0. If this is correct, then when we apply this to a smaller neighborhood, we get something that maps to the result of the same procedure applied to a larger neighborhood. This corresponds to the fact that we can extend compactly supported cohomology classes from a neighborhood to the whole thing but we can't restrict them to a neighborhood.

Comment: No, I don't extend by $0$. Possibly the confusion is caused by my notation: $i_{\epsilon}$ is an open embedding and not a closed one. Now for a point $x$ lying on the distance exactly $=\epsilon$  from $Z$ (so, it does not belong to $Z_{\epsilon}$, but belongs to its closure) the intersection of any neighbourhood of $x$ with $Z_{\epsilon}$ is not empty; hence the residue of $S_{\epsilon}$ at $x$ is non-zero (for example, for a constant $S$).

Comment: So, $S_ϵ$ is exactly $i_{\epsilon \ast} i_{\epsilon}^\ast S$, whereas $i_{ϵ!}\neq i_{ϵ\ast}$.

Comment: Mikhail -- yes, I see. But then it looks like $S_Z$ will be just the restriction of $S$ to $Z$, so the adjunction formula wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, $S_Z$ is a sheaf on $X$, and it does not vanish on $X\setminus Z$. So, what is your formula for $S_Z$?

Note that $Z_{\epsilon}\cap U$ is usually larger than $(Z\cap U)_ϵ$.

Comment: Mikhail -- I don't see why $S_Z$ does not vanish on $X\setminus Z$. If say $dist(x,Z)=a>0$, then the stalk of any $S_\epsilon, \epsilon<a$ at $x$ is 0, and hence so is the stalk of the limit. I think that `$S_Z$` is just `$i_* i^{-1}S$`.

Comment: $S_Z(U)=0$ if the closure of $U$ is disjoint from $Z$. This does not seem to imply that $S_Z(X\setminus Z)=0$. Maybe, I should have specified what does a 'sheaf' mean in this context; I do not allows coverings by infinite disjoint unions of manifolds.

Comment: Mikhail -- here is a different argument: if the stalk of $S_Z$ at some $x\in X\setminus Z$ were non-zero, then for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there would be a smaller neighborhood $V$ with $S_Z(V)\neq 0$. Now take a $U$ such that its closure does not intersect $Z$.

Comment: Yes, all these stalks are zero; yet the section $S_Z(X\setminus Z)\neq 0$. This does not seem to contradict those arguments on this subject (on stalks) that I know about.

Comment: Dear Mikhail, if $i_\ast i^\ast$ has a left adjoint say $W$, then $i^\ast$ has a left adjoint as well, as one can see, using the fact that $i_\ast$ is fully faithful, as follows: we have $Hom(F,i^\ast G)=Hom(i_\ast F, i_\ast i^\ast G)=Hom(W i_\ast F, G)$. In other words, $W i_\ast$ is then a left adjoint of $i^\ast$. Therefore, the obstructions against the existence of $W$ are the same as the ones against the existence of a left adjoint of $i^\ast$.

Comment: Mikhail -- if all stalks of a sheaf over an open set $U$ are zero, then this sheaf has no non-zero sections over any open subset of $U$.

Comment: Dear algori, it seems that one has to allow 'infinite' covers in order to prove that stalks of an non-zero sheaf (on a non-compact space) cannot be zero?

Comment: Dear Mikhail -- I'm not sure I understand this remark. But if we have a sheaf $F$ on an arbitrary topological space all of whose stalks are zero, then for any open $U$ we have $F(U)=0$, so $F$ is obtained by sheafifying the zero presheaf.

Comment: If you exclude infinite covers, you are entering unknown territory and should be careful. It's not even obvious what that means. I think the three most likely possibilities are: that they come for free; that you don't get a topos; or that you end up with sheaves on a weird space.

Comment: Yes, it seems that I do get something weird! I will write an update to my question.

Comment: Dear Mikhail -- now I'm confused by the statement that $S_Z$ does not have to be a sheaf. By definition, if $A$ is any directed set and `$F=(\{F_a\}_{a\in A}, \{f_a^b:F_a\to F_b\mid a,b\in A, a<b\}$` is a directed system of sheaves on some topological space, then the inductive limit $\mathop{\mathrm{inj}}\lim_{a\in A} F_a$ is the sheaf generated by the presheaf $U\to \mathop{\mathrm{inj}}\lim_{a\in A} F_a(U)$. This sheaf has all the expected properties (e.g. it is the colimit of $F$ in the category of sheaves; its stalks are the inductive limits of the stalks of $F_a$'s etc.), apart from one..

Comment: The only bad thing that can happen is that in general $\mathop{\mathrm{inj}}\lim_{a\in A} F_a(U)$ is not the same as the inductive limit of $F_a(U)$.

Comment: Yes; this is exactly the case! I don't want to sheafify the limit presheaf. I will now add some observations to my post.

Comment: Actually, excluding finite covers is not unknown territory. The relationship between sheaves on the site that you can get by allowing only locally finite covers and ind-sheaves has already been studied. See for example the book of Kashiwara and Schapira, "Ind-sheaves" (Astérique 271), especially chapter 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me show that $i^{-1}$ can't have a left adjoint when $X$ is a connected topological space and $Z\neq X$ is a point. From the remark by Denis-Charles Cisinski it would follow that $i_* i^{-1}$ can't have a left adjoint either.

Suppose $Z=\{x\}$ and $i^{-1}$ had a left adjoint $J$. Then we would have $$Hom (JF,G)=Hom (F,i^{-1} G)$$ for any $F$ a sheaf on $Z$ and $G$ a sheaf on $X$. Take a non-zero sheaf $F\in Sh(Z)$, i.e. a non-zero abelian group. Note that the stalk $(JF)_x\neq 0$ (this can be seen by taking $G$ to be the constant sheaf with stalk $F$). Let us show that for any $F$ the sheaf $JF$ must be supported at $x$. Suppose there is a $y\neq x$ such that $(JF)_y\neq 0$. Then take $G=i'_* i'^{-1}JF$ where $i'$ is the inclusion $\{y\}\to X$. We have $i^{-1} G=0$, and so the right hand side of the above adjunction formula is zero. The left hand side part is non-zero since the canonical map $JF\to  i'_* i'^{-1}JF$ is non-zero.

So $JF$ must be supported on $x$. Take $G$ to be the constant sheaf with stalk $F$. This time ii is the left hand side of the formula that is zero (here we use that $X$ is connected and $Z\neq X$, so $JF=i_*i^{-1} JF$ can't map into the constant sheaf $G=\underline{F}_X$ in a non-zero way) and the right hand side that isn't.